# How to configure the Flutter module in multi module project

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I have an android project that consists of many modules, some of them are dependant on another. I want to create a new module that would be used as a flutter native-part of my project.

So I want to have a structure like that:

```
- root
 |- moduleA
 |- moduleB
 |- moduleC
 |- FlutterModule
   |- lib
   |- ios
   |- android
```

FlutterModule/android project would use some of the dependencies in moduleA(that may use modules B and C).
The issue is that main build.gradle has to be in root folder, not in FlutterModule/android, as Flutter wants it to be.

Currently I cannot build Android project after opening FlutterModule, as it says that "AndroidManifest.xml" is missing, but the real issue is lack of the build.gradle in FlutterModule/android.
There's a workaround - I can build the ios code first (dart code will be compiled then), and then from my root folder I can invoke in AndroidStudio task to build FlutterModule/android module, as normal android project.
That works, but is not the way it should be handled...

I know that I should not create FlutterModule inside android/ios project, but that's the way our infrastructure works now, so I have to do it like that. No one will agree on creating plugin from this moduleA and publishing it to flutter.pub. No one will create for me CI pipeline for single Flutter project either.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is not supported for now. See this issue on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39707#issuecomment-529716918.